# How to Cast a calculated field multiplied with a money field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have tried every CAST I can think of, and the line that will not return a value is the 'Percent' value times the `P.pyd_amount` which is a `Money` field.

```
SELECT O.ord_hdrnumber, O.ord_totalweight, L.lgh_tot_weight, P.pyd_amount,  
CAST(O.ord_totalweight/L.lgh_tot_weight as decimal (10,2)) AS 'Percent', 
'Percent' * P.pyd_amount  as 'Breakdown' FROM Legheader L 
LEFT OUTER JOIN paydetail P ON (L.lgh_number = P.lgh_number) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderheader O ON (O.mov_number = L.mov_number) 
WHERE L.lgh_number = '2659'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Percent` is a  alias column name which is not allowed the way you used in calculation , you have to use that expression directly for calculation

```
select O.ord_hdrnumber, O.ord_totalweight, L.lgh_tot_weight, P.pyd_amount,  
Cast (O.ord_totalweight/L.lgh_tot_weight as decimal (10,2)) as 'Percent', 
Cast (O.ord_totalweight/L.lgh_tot_weight as decimal (10,2)) * P.pyd_amount  as 'Breakdown' from Legheader L 
Left outer join paydetail P on (L.lgh_number = P.lgh_number) 
left outer join orderheader O on (O.mov_number = L.mov_number) 
where L.lgh_number = '2659'
```

Comment: Thank you SOOO Much, I am a new SQL user, and learning from the help of people like you. You saved my night!!! It worked brilliantly.